# How can I change the column names to lower case values in BigQuery TableResults using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I retrieve the table results as below

```
        val queryJob = bigQuery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).build())
        val tableResults = queryJob.getQueryResults()
```

How can I modify the tableResults such a way that all the column names are converted to lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it for your original question, taking a `List<Map<String, Any>>` and converting all the `String` keys to lowercase:

```
val lowered = listOfMaps.map { someMap ->
    someMap.mapKeys { (key, value) -> key.toLowerCase() }
}
```

The term `map` is a little confusing when you're also talking about `Map`s, but you're transforming each `Map` in the list by calling [`mapKeys`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-keys.html) on it, which takes a function that produces a new key for each entry.

I don't know what type `tableResults` is but I'm assuming it's that. If not, hopefully this helps you work out what you need to do